# Setting analyser during indexing in ElasticSearch using JAVA API

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer.html

I have to use **standard** analyzer during **indexing** with custom **stopwords** .

How can the mappings be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will set standard analyzer with custom set of stopwords as a default analyzer for the index `testidx`:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/testidx/ -d '{
  "settings":{ 
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "default":{
          "type":"standard",
          "stopwords":["foo", "bar", "baz"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Or if you want to use custom stopwords **only** for indexing:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/testidx/ -d '{
  "settings":{ 
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "default_index":{
          "type":"standard",
          "stopwords":["foo", "bar", "baz"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: What if i want to define different analyzers for different fields?

Comment: If you replace "default" with some other name it will define a new analyzer with such name and you can assign it to any field in your mapping.